# Parallelized reticulate call with foreach failing

Tags: python, r, foreach, parallel-processing, reticulate

Hi I am trying to call a python function with reticulate in a parallel manner using `foreach` like so:

```
library(reticulate)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)

py_install("wandb")
wandb <- import("wandb")


cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = 'PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
    wandb$init(project = "test")
}
```

gives:

```
Error in {: task 1 failed - "attempt to apply non-function"
Traceback:

1. foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
 .     wandb$init(project = "test")
 . }
2. e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
```

Does the `foreach` package not work with reticulate?

Comment: What kind of object is `wandb`? I think `wandb$init(project = "test")` doesn't work since this mixes somehow a data based operator `$` with a function `( ... )`. Perhaps you wanted something like `wandb$init[project == "test"]` (which most likely won't work either... perhaps `wandb$init[wandb$project == "test"]`).

Comment: wandb is a python library imported via reticulate.

Comment: Does it use this special syntax? Because in `R` I would expect some slight syntactical changes.

Comment: There's no way it's going to work,`reticulate` doesn't support multithreading because the entire python session is embedded in the parent R session. If you want to do it in parallel, import the function from within each child R process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot export **reticulate** `python.builtin.module` objects from one R process to another. They are designed to only work within the same R process they're created. If attempted, then you'll get the error you're reporting.

If you use **future** framework for your parallelization, then you can have it check for this and give an informative error message immediately, e.g.

```
library(reticulate)
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(2L)
plan(cluster, workers = cl)

## Detect non-exportable objects and give an error asap
options(future.globals.onReference = "error")

# py_install("wandb")
wandb <- import("wandb")

res <- foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  wandb$init(project = "test")
  sqrt(i)
}
```

The call to `foreach()` will result in:

```
Error: Detected a non-exportable reference ('externalptr') in one of
the globals ('wandb' of class 'python.builtin.module') used in the
future expression
```

You can read more about this in https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html#package-reticulate.

A workaround would be create the `wandb` object within each iteration, which runs on the worker end.  Something like:

```
res <- foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  wandb <- import("wandb")
  wandb$init(project = "test", mode = "offline")
  sqrt(i)
}
```

Disclaimer: I know nothing about the 'wandb' Python module.  Maybe the above doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks @HenrikB for the explanation and workaround.